# How to make the CombinedChart-BarChart average distributed on the x-axis？

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I use `MpAndroidChart-CombinedChart` in my project,but I met a problem,please look the follow screenshot.

[image: Graph]
As you saw，the X axis right part didn't filled.In other words,I want set the bar space，but I can't.

I try `barData.setBarWidth(0.4f)`,it didn't work,it will make the bar width Larger，but it will not make bar space lager.

```
 public static void initCombinedChart(List<FieldFragment.CombinedBean> list, CombinedChart combinedChart) {
    if (list == null || list.size() == 0) return;
    combinedChart.setPinchZoom(false);
    combinedChart.setDragEnabled(false);
    combinedChart.setTouchEnabled(false);
    combinedChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    combinedChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

    XAxis xAxis = combinedChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setYOffset(5);
    xAxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);

    YAxis leftYAxis = combinedChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftYAxis.setLabelCount(6, true);
    leftYAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    leftYAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
    leftYAxis.setGridColor(Color.parseColor("#DDDDDD"));
    leftYAxis.setXOffset(10f);
    leftYAxis.setAxisMinimum(0);
    leftYAxis.setSpaceBottom(0);
    leftYAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);

    YAxis rightYAxis = combinedChart.getAxisRight();
    rightYAxis.setSpaceBottom(0);
    rightYAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    rightYAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
    rightYAxis.setAxisMinimum(0);
    rightYAxis.setXOffset(10);
    rightYAxis.setLabelCount(6, true);
    rightYAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);

    List<Entry> lineEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    List<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> xValues = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        lineEntries.add(new Entry(i, list.get(i).getRightYValue()));
        barEntries.add(new BarEntry(i, list.get(i).getLeftYValue()));
        xValues.add(list.get(i).getxValue());
    }
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axisBase) {
            try {
                int position = (int) value;
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                Date date = dateFormat.parse(xValues.get(position));
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd");
                return format.format(date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    });

    // 折线数据
    LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(lineEntries, "");
    lineDataSet.setDrawValues(false);
    lineDataSet.setDrawCircles(false);
    lineDataSet.setLineWidth(3f);
    lineDataSet.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00c2bd"));
    lineDataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.HORIZONTAL_BEZIER);
    lineDataSet.setDrawFilled(true); //这个不要忘了
    lineDataSet.setFillColor(Color.parseColor("#00c2bd"));
    lineDataSet.setFillAlpha(50);
    lineDataSet.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    List<ILineDataSet> lineDataSets = new ArrayList<>();
    lineDataSets.add(lineDataSet);
    LineData lineData = new LineData(lineDataSets);

    // 柱子数据
    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "");
    barDataSet.setDrawValues(false);
    barDataSet.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
    barDataSet.setColor(Color.parseColor("#1490ee"));
    BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
    barData.setBarWidth(0.4f); //值越大柱子越宽


    // 解决bar显示不全问题
    float barWidth = barData.getBarWidth() / 2;
    xAxis.setAxisMinimum(-barWidth);
    xAxis.setAxisMaximum(xValues.size() - barWidth);

    CombinedData combinedData = new CombinedData();
    combinedData.setData(lineData);
    combinedData.setData(barData);
    combinedChart.setData(combinedData);
    combinedChart.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your code and data. I can play with it and maybe find solution

Comment: I have put the code,thanks